# unexpected argument pass order employing stl numeric

Tags: c++, stl

I think I am missing something in the following code the output of the last two call iterating with only one element of container in the accumulate results in passing that one element as the second argument instead of first or I haven't get the idea of how utilizing it yet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int foo(int x, int y) {return 2*x+y;}
int foo2(int x, int y) {return x+2*y;}

int main() {

    array<int, 2> arr {{1, 2}};
    cout << accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0)
         << endl; // 1 + 2 = 3 as expected
    cout << accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0, foo)
         << endl; // 2*1+2 = 4 as expected
    cout << accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end()-1, 0, foo)
         << endl; // not 2*1+0 but 2*0+1 => 1!
    cout << accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end()-1, 0, foo2)
         << endl; // not 1+2*0 but 0+2*1 = > 2!

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
3
4
1
2
```

Comment: `accumulate` always passes the value-so-far as the first argument and the next element of the range as the second argument to the functor. Was this not what you expected, or is something else causing the confusion?

Comment: I am expecting to see 3,4,2,1 or since I am passing only one element in the last two calls 3,4,1,1. but it looks like when I am passing one element it uses y arg for it and consider the first argument as zero

Comment: The second call to accumulate does the same. It calls foo(0, 1) and foo(1,2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument of `accumulate` is the initial accumulation value. It is thus passed as the first argument of the first call to the accumulation function. You have correctly deduced the calculation of the last two values:

```
accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end()-1, 0, foo)
// = foo(0, 1) = 2*0 + 1 = 1
accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end()-1, 0, foo2)
// = foo2(0, 1) = 0 + 2*1 = 2
```

Hwoever, the first two values are calculated in exactly the same way:

```
accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0)
// = add(add(0, 1), 2) = (0 + 1) + 2 = 3
accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0, foo)
// = foo(foo(0, 1), 2) = 2*(2*0 + 1) + 2 = 4
```

It is simply by accident that calculation you (incorrectly) expected yields the same results in these two cases.

Comment: And I think for this one accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.begin(), 3, foo) the function would n't apply since the result stay the same (3) . is that correct.

Comment: @AMCoded Yes. There is nothing to accumulate, so the function is never called and the initial value is returned.